# how to check whether appium driver is live

Tags: appium

I have a scenario where after I disable a button, I check for the data persistence in the database. It takes some time to persist data in the database( roughly 3 mins). My tests are started through sauce labs so after 90 seconds the time out and my session is closed.
I do take screenshots of the tests at the tearDown Method. when data persistence takes more than 90 seconds the screenshots method is failing. I want to take screenshots only when the driver is alive, how can I check for it?

````
  
                    takeAllureScreenShot();
              
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increase how long Sauce Labs waits before shutting down a session by configuring the `idleTimeout` desired capability (docs for which are [here](https://docs.saucelabs.com/dev/test-configuration-options/#idletimeout)).

By default, this is set to 90 seconds; It sounds like you should increase it to something like 200 seconds.

Assuming you're using Java and a Selenium 3 session with vendor name-spacing, you could do that like so:

```java
    // This is a new capabilities object to hold the nested vendor-specific options
    MutableCapabilities sauceOptions = new MutableCapabilities();
    sauceOptions.setCapability("idleTimeout", 200);

    // assuming your desired capabilities are called 'capabilities'
    capabilities.setCapability("sauce:options", sauceOptions);
```

(If you just wanted to check that the session was still alive, you could do so by doing something "trivial" like checking the page title inside an try/catch block.  If an exception is thrown, the session is over!  If you get a response, it's not).